# Optimizing Session Scheduling for Trainees in a Batch-Based System

Tags: visual-workflow, cross-object

[image]

[image]

I have 3 objects Batch, Trainee and Session; where batch is parent of Trainee and Session. Few sessions are created in chunks when batch is created and each particular session has  pre-decided interval between them.
I have to create a solution where if a trainee misses a session then that respective trainee should be included in the next upcoming session. or with the next batch.

Comment: Hi and welcome to SFSE. Please take a minute to read [How to Ask](/help/how-to-ask) and perhaps take the [tour] then [edit] your question to explain what you have done and where you are stuck. We are here to help you with specific technical challenges, not as a free design or coding service. Without showing your effort and focusing on specific technical challenges this question is likely to be closed without answer.